# Parsing with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing HTML using Nokogiri, and then getting these type elements.

```html
<li data-item="{"title":"where is title","slug":"about some",
    "has_many_images":false,"show_image":"abbxb","created_at":1373737401,
    "show_attr":{"value":"150"},
    "location":"Alabama",
    "category":"Table",
    "is_business":false}">

    //here other many more
</li>
```

Now I want to get this `data-item`, I'm using:

```ruby
 page.css("li[data-item]")[0]
```

I'm getting something like this:

`#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14fc250 name="li" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x14fc178 name="class" value="item">,` and so on ...

But I want like this:

```
"{"title":"where is title","slug":"about some",
        "has_many_images":false,"show_image":"abbxb","created_at":1373737401,
        "show_attr":{"value":"150"},
        "location":"Alabama",
        "category":"Table",
        "is_business":false}"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: @nano.galvao nice edit.. I learnt today from you.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that attribute with the following selection:

```
page.at_xpath("//li[1]/@data-item").content
```

**EDIT**

A more complete demonstration, at @Priti's request:

```
body = %Q{     
  <body>
    <li data-item='{"title":"where is title","slug":"about some",
      "has_many_images":false,"show_image":"abbxb","created_at":1373737401,
      "show_attr":{"value":"150"},
      "location":"Alabama",
      "category":"Table",
      "is_business":false}'>
    </li>
  </body>
}
page = Nokogiri::XML(body)
result = page.at_xpath("//li[1]/@data-item").content
# "{\"title\":\"where is title\",\"slug\":\"about some\",         \"has_many_images\":false,\"show_image\":\"abbxb\",\"created_at\":1373737401,         \"show_attr\":{\"value\":\"150\"},         \"location\":\"Alabama\",         \"category\":\"Table\",         \"is_business\":false}"
```

Comment: The `data-item` attribute value as described by the asker is not valid. I assumed he or she properly escaped the quotes. For example, my selector works if you wrap the attribute value with single quotes.

Comment: I tried but getting only `""`. " :) I want you also try once you will have time.

Comment: I just tried with the asker's example, only substituting `data-item=' ... '` for `data-item=" ... "`. With this selector I get exactly what the asker is looking for.

Comment: @Priti: Yes, I'm getting absolutely, what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: @kardeiz could you post your code? I may then post also the answer i am having. But something went wrong with me. probably if I see yours,I would catch my falsy part. would you share ?